# Validate against a list in Excel

Tags: excel

I have the below working so that if `f15 = X` it allows a drop down selection of values from `Mylist`

```
=IF($F15="X", Mylist, FALSE)
```

I want to be able to make it so that if `f15 = any value` from another list to allow a drop down selection from Mylist.

I thought the following would work but It doesnt seem to.

```
=IF($F15=List2, Mylist, FALSE)
```

List2:

```
X
Y
Z
```

In other words if f15 contains either x, y, or z, I want to be able to select from the dropdown values of Mylist.

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF(List2,$F15)>0,MyList,"")`

Comment: Returns error saying list must be delimited or a reference to a single row or column

Answer (score 0):

From tigeravatar

=IF(COUNTIF(List2,$F15)>0,MyList,"")